# Неосознанная грамотность

Tags: общие-вопросы

Вопрос, наверное, не по теме, но захотелось это обсудить. Я заметила, что при быстром наборе текста на клавиатуре делаю ошибки. Причем не просто "опечатки", когда палец попадает на соседнюю клавишу или правая рука обгоняет левую. "Настоящие" ошибки, т.е., например, "а" вместо "о". А ведь эти буквы на клавиатуре не рядом!
При писании рукой этого не наблюдается. Конечно, этот процесс более медленный и есть время "подумать". Но ведь на самом деле рукой я пишу тоже автоматически, не обращаясь мысленно к правилам! Получается, что есть как бы разная глубина усвоения навыка.
Замечал ли кто-либо за собой такую "неграмотность"? Если да, что, по-вашему, может быть ее причиной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разумеется. Это один из известных видов дисграфии (под которой я разумею письменную дислексию, тут разнобой в терминологии). 
Типичные ошибки: замена букв по омофоническому признаку (безударных гласных и оглушаемых согласных) и замена на парные по глухости-звонкости согласные даже в сильных позициях.
Всё это наблюдается при общей грамотности, т.е. о незнании правил речи не идёт.
Обычно проявляется либо при рукописном письме, либо при наборе, редко - одновременно. Связано с тем, что в этих случаях задействованы разные психомоторные навыки.
Но общая схема дисфункции состоит в том, что пищущий проговаривает "про себя" текст - и поскольку в описанных случаях возбуждаются одни и те же зоны, происходит смешение сигнала.

Говорю как человек, сам этим расстройством страдающий, по счастью - не в самой сильной степени.

Кстати насчёт "сиводня". Насколько понимаю, такое написание для рассматриваемого синдрома нехарактерно. Скорее уж "се**к**одня". Тут не просто фонетическое соответствие, а сходность психомоторики.

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение, мне было интересно, насколько это типично.  

Сейчас не могу вспомнить, действительно ли когда-нибудь писала "сиводня". Попробую следить за своими ошибками и составить их каталог!

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая проблема.Видимо, рука "запоминает" написание слова и пишет сама. Ведь при написании новых, незнакомых слов мы задумываемся, а не пишем их автоматически. При работе на клавиатуре у руки такой памяти нет. Может, у нового поколения она и будет... Ну вот так. Интересно, конечно, что по этому поводу думают другие участники нашего портала.

Answer (score 0):

Таких ошибок не делаю; я, когда печатаю. смотрю на монитор, у меня один палец или одна рука впереди другой бежит. А рукодвигательная (моторная) память действительно существует. Но обычно  все виды памяти: и зрительная, и слуховая, и моторная  - месте работают. У Вас, видно, моторная развита лучше других. Либо Вы не смотрите на монитор и нет работы для Вашей зрительной памяти.

Comment: Я смотрю на клавиатуру (в основном). Мне просто странно, что я могу написать с дикими ошибками, как совершенно неграмотный человек.  
Например, "севодня" и т.п. Т.е. пишу на фонетическом уровне!  

Получается очень странно: когда пишу рукой, использую, так сказать, письменную речь, а когда (очень быстро) на клавиатуре  - звуковую!

Answer (score 0):

Существует слепой метод набора. Вот он, как мне кажется,способствует связному запоминанию написаний. В этом случае можно не смотреть ни на пальцы, ни на монитор, а только в оригинал, если идёт перепечатка. Что до будущих поколений, то их мозг вполне может приспособиться к меняющимся условиям. Слышала, что в западных странах уже есть дети, которых с раннего детства не заставляли писать ручкой. У нас же, скорее всего, найдутся асы, с одинаковым успехом владеющие всеми методами создания текста.

Answer (score 0):

Бывает такое. Как заметил, происходит это чаще всего когда устал, и быстро печатаю сообщение в диалоге с друзьями. Думаю, это связано с тем, что из-за скорости ответа на реплики, я подсознательно воспринимаю печатаемое и читаемое, как аудио-диалог и осознано (смайлы) или невольно, начинаю переносить фонетические нормы в письменную речь. Как подтверждение этой версии заметил, что при более длительном ответе на мои сообщения, подобных проблем за собой не замечал.

Answer (score 0):

А если ты печатаешь одни слова, а в напечатанном тексте видишь совсем другие?
Т.е. "тебя" - "себя", "меня", "услышишь" - "услышал", т.е. разные глагольные формы. Грамотность при этом отличная. Я уже думала, что компьютер как-то сам преобразует напечатанное, если ему такой вариант кажется более вероятным.